# Detect if an Input has Changed dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

Other javascript is changing the value of an input and I was wondering if there was a way to detect the change.

This question has nothing to do with Keyup or Change.  This is not being typed in by the user it is being changed by other javascript though various actions of the user.

Comment: You could always poll it using a setInterval call. Not elegant though.

Comment: Do you've a code example?

Comment: do you have control over that other javascript? If so, you could fire some sort of event when you change it

Comment: A lot of inputs that could change.  I can build it into the program changing the inputs, but I was hoping there was a more elegant methodology.

Comment: As far as I know there is no such event, except polling etc, and you could try the not so well supported oninput event, but doubt that will work! Using trigger('change') when changing the value is the easiest.

Comment: There is no "change change" event. You'll need a setInterval or teach your other scripts to use an event delegation framework to notify you of changes.

Comment: Adeneo, I tried input, it does not work.  I may use the Trigger event. Thank you. Please post that as an answer and I will accept :)

Comment: Adeneo I edited after you did please re-read.

Comment: @Iscariot - Sure, added! Calling trigger() will trigger the event handler, and is quite convenient when changing values dynamically !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When changing an event programatically, you can trigger a change event to make sure event handlers that are attached to the element are fired. jQuery has a `trigger()` method to do this:

```
$('#elementID').on('change', function() {
    alert( this.value );
});


$('#elementID').val('some new value').trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 0):

The quick run-down of what I am going to say is: there is no way other than to modify the third-party scripts to output stuff, or to use `setInterval` (costly).

The bottom line of this issue is a simple one, that does not appear to be so at first: **How can you get your scrips to communicate with each other?**

When a script modifies the value of an input through JS methods (i.e. not user input), they have to go through specific hoops to get the "change" event to fire (they can fire it manually by calling it, which most devs never do and is easily forgotten when writing code). In practice, people tend to rely on the observation **events** (user-defined ones) to track code changes. This is very similar to DOM events - you bind callbacks to your script, which allow you to tap callbacks in that will fire whenever your scripts do something interesting (like modifying inputs. This is just one example). You then teach your scripts and developers to fire events on useful stuff using the callbacks to notify other scripts.

A great library for this is [Postal](https://github.com/postaljs), which is originally a Node library. jQuery also has an event system you can tap into. However, if you want to roll your own, all you have to read into is the Observer design pattern. It is trivial: you bind a function to your object to pick up callbacks, and another to fire them. Whenever you change the thing, you fire the callback. Simples.

Failure to do so means `setInterval`. Sucks, but there you go :-(